# How to select a N number of checkboxes using console?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, checkbox, chrome-app-developer-tool

I'm trying to select a N number of checkboxes of a list by console, but I don't know exactly how to do it.
I have this list of data, and I have to delete all registers, but the system doesn't allows me to delete more than 200 items, and my "check all" button checks more than 200 items. So I decided to check the checkboxes using the Console. Can someone help me? Each checkbox has a name: "msgid1", "msgid2", "msgid3"...

my progress so far:

```js
for(i = 1, i < 10, i++){
  var myList = document.getElementsByName("msgid"+i); 
  myList[0].prop("checked", true);
}
```

P.S.: I don't have permission to edit the code.
Thank you.

Comment: Can you set up a JSFiddle please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the selector `input[name*='msgid` will grab all inputs that start with "msgid"

and if you wanted to check all of them then set `var number = list.length`

https://jsfiddle.net/n0sytxd9/

```
var list = $("input[name*='msgid']");
var number = 5;

if(number<list.length)
for(var i=0;i<number;i++){
    $(list[i]).attr('checked',true);   
}
```

Comment: Thanks godmode. That's what I was looking for

Comment: np @FelipeLeal, happy to help